# How do I do a mass email to all volunteers?

Tags: civimail

I am very new to civi and am needing advice on now to do a mass email to all volunteers. I have the language that is to be used in the body of the email. I will copy and paste this to the "Group" or "Mass" email. Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

welcome to CiviCRM!

How are your volunteers defined in the CRM? I.e.how do you create a volunteer instead of a regular contact?

When you know that, log in, go to search -> advanced search. It's worth getting familiar with these options. Look to see if volunteer appears under contact type.

If you need more info post back!

John